# My <div> is sticking to the corner

Tags: css

Here is my relevant code for the `#blogtitle` element:

```
#blogtitle{
 width: 125px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #883322;
 font-family: Georgia;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-left: 25px;
 margin: 10px;
}

#blogtitle a{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#blogtitle a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

...

```
<div id="blogtitle">
 <a href="#">fdsfdj</a>
</div>
```

When I make a webpage with nothing but the `div` and `a` on it, it sticks to the corner, even though I have set `margin: 10px`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/TwTPX/ Not sure it helps the OP's argument (at least in FF4).

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted your css and html. Did I get it right?

Comment: It works in JSFiddle, and not in the page that I am editing. Odd...

Comment: I hope you wouldn't mind asking if you are linking the stylesheet correctly. Maybe, you're not linking the external stylesheet properly. It works in my browser Google Chrome. I can upload a screenshot to see if that is what you intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

> display: table-cell;

to

> display: block;

this will solve the problem.

Comment: This is correct, but I'm guessing you wanted to use the table-cell display style to get "vertical-align: middle" to work.  Another option is to wrap the #blogtitle in another div:  http://jsfiddle.net/kpespisa/9VjNF/1/

Comment: @awesomeguy, that is a different problem. You should accept this answer as correct. Table cells cannot have margin (neither can elements with `display: table-cell`).